# How do I supplant jQuery's toggleClass method with pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I turn this piece of jQuery code into JavaScript?

```
$('#element').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('class1 class2')
});
```

I have already tried the following pieces of code, but to no avail.

First one is:

```
var element = document.getElementById('element'),
    classNum = 0; // Supposing I know that the first time there will be that class
element.onmousedown = function() {
    if (classNum === 0) {
        this.classList.remove("class1");
        this.classList.add("class2");
        classNum = 1;
    }
    else if (classNum === 1) {
        this.classList.remove("class2");
        this.classList.add("class1");
        classNum = 0;
    }
}
```

Second one is:

```
var element = document.getElementById('element'),
    classNum = 0; // Supposing I know that the first time there will be that class
element.onmousedown = function() {
    if (classNum === 0) {
        this.className -= "class1";
        this.classList += "class2";
        classNum = 1;
    }
    else if (classNum === 1) {
        this.classList -= "class2";
        this.classList += "class1";
        classNum = 0;
    }
}
```

Any answer that doesn't suggest that I stick with jQuery will be greatly appreciated.

**[EDIT]**

I've tried all of your solutions, but haven't been able to get it right. I believe it's because I didn't state clearly that the element has multiple classes like so:

```
class="class1 class3 class4"
```

And what I want is basically to replace class1 with class2 and toggle between them.

Comment: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#toggle_class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:**
In response to comments, **classList.toggle is a pure javascript** solution. It has nothing to do with jQuery as one comment implies. If there is a requirement to support old versions of IE then there is a shim (pollyfill) at the MDN link below. And this shim, if needed, is far superior to the accepted answer.

Using [classList.toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Methods) certainly seems like the simplest solution. Also see [Can I Use classList](http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist) for browser support.

```
element.onclick = function() {
  'class1 class2'.split(' ').forEach(function(s) {
      element.classList.toggle(s);
  });
}
```

**Run the snippet to try**

```js
box.onclick = function() {
  'class1 class2'.split(' ').forEach(function(s) {
    box.classList.toggle(s);
    stdout.innerHTML = box.className;
  });
}


/* alternative 
box.onclick = function() {
  ['class1', 'class2'].forEach(function(s) {
    box.classList.toggle(s);
    stdout.innerHTML = box.className;
  });
}
*/
```

```css
.class1 { background-color: red;}
.class2 { background-color: blue;}
.class3 { width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 1px black solid;}
```

```html
click me:
<div id="box" class="class1 class3"></div>

<div id="stdout"></div>
```

Comment: Your solution was succinct and right on point. The best by far! Thanks for the references to mozilla.org too, @ Roberto!

Comment: @AngelPolitis .toggle is a jQuery function... you had originally asked for a pure JS solution. If you still want a pure JS solution look at [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37170527/4411339)

Comment: Yeah this will work great in everything except IE.  http://caniuse.com/#search=classList

Answer (score 2):

`classNum` is a local variable.

Every time the event handler is called, you get a new variable, which has nothing to do with the value from the last call.

You want that to be a global variable.

Or, better yet, check `classList.contains` instead.

Comment: I haven't had realized that the variable was reset to 0 on each click! classList.contains worked better!

Comment: @AngelPolitis: It isn't reset; it's a new variable entirely.

Comment: An entirely new variable that is set to equal to 0. That's what I meant ;)

Answer (score 2):

From: [You might not need jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)

```
$(el).toggleClass(className);
```

Is replaced by:

```
if (el.classList) {
  el.classList.toggle(className);
} else {
  var classes = el.className.split(' ');
  var existingIndex = classes.indexOf(className);

  if (existingIndex >= 0)
    classes.splice(existingIndex, 1);
  else
    classes.push(className);

  el.className = classes.join(' ');
}
```

Then simply wrap that function call within a `document.getElementById('elementId').click`

Comment: Your code @Phil looks right to me, but when I try to implement it for an element with multiple classes I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2ch8ztdk/

```
var s = document.getElementById('element');
s.onclick=function(){
  if(s.className == "class1"){
    s.className = "class2"
  } else {
    s.className = "class1"
  }
}
```

Comment: In the example, OP has assigned multiple classes to the element. One or more classes might be present and appear in any order. How would this solution solve this problem?

Comment: I think all he wants to do is toggle class1 for class2 and vice versa.

Comment: Hey @Timothy Kanski, I used your code for another element with one class as it is simple and it works. In the case of multiple classes though, it overwrote all of them :D

Comment: For this case, I will stick with @Roberto 's solution. It's short and comfortable.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is close, but your classNum variable isn't iterative. Try this:

```js
var element = document.getElementById("element");
var numCount = 0;

element.addEventListener('click', function() {
 if (numCount === 0) {
  this.className = "";
        this.className += " class1";
        numCount++;
 } else {
        this.className = "";
  this.className += " class2";
        numCount = 0;
 }
});
```

```css
.class1 {
  color: red;
}
.class2 {
  color: blue;  
}
```

```html
<div id="element">click me</div>
```

Comment: Hey @Sean Henderson, I like your solution as it is closer to my way of thinking. I don't think it would work, though, if the element has more than one classes.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `classList`, but it only support IE 10+

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/qLRRIwfgzII5sLmMio1y?p=preview)

```
  var eles = document.querySelectorAll('#element');
  var classNames = 'one two';

  for(var i = 0; i < eles.length; i ++){
    eles[i].onclick = function(e){
      toggleClass.call(this, classNames);
    }
  }

  function toggleClass(names){
    var sp = names.split(' ');
    for(var i = 0; i < sp.length; i++){
      this.classList.toggle(sp[i]);
    }

  }
```

Comment: Hey @MarkoCen, is there a specific reason why you declared the variable using _**document.querySelectorAll('#element');**_ instead of _**document.getElementById('element');**_ ?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED MY ANSWER TO SUPPORT MULTIPLE CLASSES PER ELEMENT**

https://jsfiddle.net/pwyncL8r/2/  This will now allow the element to already have *n* classes and still swap only one, retaining the other classes.

**HTML**

```
<div id="div1" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" class="backBlack left100"</div>
<input type="button" id="swapButton" value="Css Swap" />
```

**CSS**

```
.backBlack {
    background-color: black;
}

.backRed {
    background-color: red;
}

.left100 {
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

**JS**

```
swapButton.onclick = function() {
    var curClassIsBlack = (' ' + document.getElementById("div1").className + ' ').indexOf(' backBlack ') > -1
    if (curClassIsBlack) {
        document.getElementById("div1").className =
        document.getElementById("div1").className.replace(/(?:^|\s)backBlack(?!\S)/g, '')
        document.getElementById("div1").className += " backRed";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("div1").className =
        document.getElementById("div1").className.replace(/(?:^|\s)backRed(?!\S)/g,'')
        document.getElementById("div1").className += " backBlack";
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this work in case of having multiple class in the element?

Comment: @AngelPolitis i've updated my answer to allow the element to have multiple classes.

Comment: Your comment about toggle being jQuery is incorrect. classList.toggle is pure javascript and is supported by all modern browsers. And there is a shim available for older browsers that is far superior to a hard coded solution.